# Thunderbird FireTray Add-on - Must close twice

Tags: 11.10, unity, thunderbird

I've installed Thunderbird and FireTray addon, then checked to minimize to tray on close.
Now, if I start Thunderbird after quitting (Win+Q) and try to close with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>:

- for the first time it's minimised properly to tray
- on each next time I need to double press "close button", and if the window is not maximised
- firstly it maximizes (first <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>), then closes(second <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>)

Could you help me, please?

Ubuntu 11.10, Unity 2d

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem in that I would lose the menu after opening and closing Thunderbird a few times whenever Minimize to Tray Revived was activated.

A workaround was to actually disable Global Menu Bar Integration. Then you use Thunderbird's native menu when Minimize to Tray crashes Unity's.

Answer (score 0):

it behaves in an odd fashion for me in Unity (normal, compiz version). Basically I don't think it plays nice with Unity as things stand. It also loses its global menu after several open/close cycles.